# Is there a way in MySQL to have one column be just a reference to another column on the same table?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to have one column be just a reference to another column on the same table?

I am dealing with a really old MySQL database that has no naming conventions.  I can't just rename the columns because that would break a lot of code. So I thought it would be cool if I could add a "shortcut column" to the poorly named column and then use them interchangeably.

Comment: Do you have the ability to use a view instead of the table, or is switching out the table name for the view name a non-starter?

Comment: Yep, using a view to support the legacy code was my first idea as well. It would give you time to transition the code over to new tables, over time.

Comment: IMO, use aliases in your queries if you have to, but I suspect being able to call a column by 2 names is going to add _more_ confusion to a possibly already confusing situation.(Yes you can use triggers etc. to keep another column in sync, but I as a potentially fellow coder emplore you to keep things clear. Don't make me look for hours why one column changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [creating a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)?

```
CREATE VIEW view_name 
AS SELECT *, bad_name as New_name
FROM table
```

Comment: I was thinking hypothetically create a view with the same column names, then swap out the table for the view in the piles of ASP.NET that use it, then i could change the column name... does that sound rational?

Comment: Sounds logical, just be sure to keep the [view limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-restrictions.html) in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'reference' (an example would be nice), but... in the SQL statement, you can define the same column multiple times and specify an alias to the column name.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *, [this_is_a_really_bad_name] as myNewName FROM MyTable
```

Assuming the table `MyTable` has the badly designed column `this_is_a_really_bad_name`, you can now refer to that column by its old name or as `myNewName`

Is that what you are trying to achieve?